# Refactoring to enum to enum class shadows namespace

Tags: c++, c++11

In previous codebase I have :

```
namespace E {
enum { a, b }
void foo();
}
```

I want to refactor to using `enum class`:

```
enum class E : int { a, b }
namespace E {
void foo();
}
```

However this fails to compile because now `namespace E` can't be used as it has same name as `enum`.
Is there a way around this ?
Basically I still want that the calling code compile as-is, which is using either `E::foo()` or `E::a`

Comment: "I still want that the calling code compile as-is, which is using either E::foo() or E::a" then whats wrong with the original?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 mostly type-safety.
I want stronger checks when comparing int to enum values. Also now I can put the enum value as uint64 for instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other way to do that is define an enum class and then map its values to respective constants:

```cpp
namespace E {
    enum class MyEnum { a, b };
    constexpr auto a = MyEnum::a;
    constexpr auto b = MyEnum::b;

    void foo() {}
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zY5v3G

This way strong type checking will be introduced and depending code will not have to be altered. More typing, but doesn't require C++20, it will work with C++11.

Comment: This is the exact technique the standards committee used when changing the _memory_order_  enum to an enum class in c++20.

Answer (score 5):

> Basically I still want that the calling code compile as-is, which is using either E::foo() or E::a

No, you cannot do that, one of the advantages of `enum class` is not polluting the outer namespace. The other is no implicit conversions.

Starting with C++20 it is possible to explicitly request the name injection with `using enum E;`

```cpp
enum class E : int { foo, bar };

using enum E;

int main()
{
    E x = foo; // Now works
    E y = E::bar; // Still works
}
```